# Sending virtual file as MultipartEntity

Tags: java

I want to send the contents of a file as `org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity`. The problem is, that I don't really have a file but only the content as `String`. The following test works perfectly, where `file` is a `java.io.File` pointing to a valid png-file:

```
MultipartEntity entity = 
  new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
entity.addPart("source", new StringBody("computer"));
entity.addPart("filename", new FileBody(file, "image/png"));
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL);
httpPost.setEntity(entity);
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

final HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
```

Later, I won't have a real file but only its content as `String`. I don't know much about encoding (not to say nothing) but if I try the same approach with a temporary file which was created in the following way

```
String contents = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(path),"UTF8");
File tmpFile = File.createTempFile("image", "png");
tmpFile.deleteOnExit();
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(contents.getBytes("UTF8"));
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);
org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(in, out);
```

The `path` points to exactly the same png-file which succeeded in the first code block but this time I get a

> Failed to upload image; the format is not supported

error from the server. I suspect is has something to do with the encoding. Does someone see what obvious thing I did wrong?

Comment: it seems "contents" is a binary file, not something that can be converted to a String

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use **readFileToString**, but **readFileToByteArray**, and don't store content in a String, but in a byte[]:

```
byte[] contents = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File(path));
File tmpFile = File.createTempFile("image", "png");
tmpFile.deleteOnExit();
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(contents);
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);
org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(in, out);
```

Comment: Thanks. I wouldn't have come up with using `String`'s myself, but the interface between *Mathematica* and Java is a bit unclear in this case. While I *can* represent even binary stuff with a `String` in *Mathematica*, it gets screwed up when I send it to Java. Anyway, converting it to a list of numbers (bytes) works excellent.